# Entity Framework translate method call

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework core 6 with SQL Server. I have the following query:

```
dbContext.Table1
    .Where(t1 => some_condition(t1.some_property))
    .Select(t1 => new
    {
       Field1 = t1.some_property,
       Field2 = dbContext.Table2.Where(t2 => some_condition(t1.some_property, t2.some_property)).First(), // <-- this is my question
    });
```

The thing is that this subquery `dbContext.Table2.Where(t2 => some_condition(t1, t2)).First(),` is used in many other places. I need to extract it somehow and call it instead of copy-pasting it everywhere.

I tried to extract it in a function like this:

```
public string Get(string some_property) => context.Table2
    .Where(t => some_condition(some_property, t.some_property))
    .First();
```

```
dbContext.Table1
    .Where(t1 => some_condition(t1.some_property))
    .Select(t1 => new
    {
       Field1 = t1.some_property,
       Field2 = Get(t1.some_property)
    });
```

But with that I get the subquery to execute separately and for every element in the collection (N+1 problem. I was expecting it though).

Is there a way to achieve that ? maybe using expression trees (which I'm not yet very familiar with).

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70929584/10646316)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you for the suggestion. I will keep that as a last resort. I want to avoid adding a dependency on a library.

Comment: Actually you have only one option - repeat that by yourself.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Can you please post an answer to show how to solve this particular issue using LinqKit? My subquery uses the context object and I can't figure out how to pass that. I'm getting the Exception "This linq query could not be translated. Either rewrite it or switch to client side..."

Comment: If you are expanding method of class instance, you should return `Expression<MyClass, string> GetImpl() => c => c.context...` like [here](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/85daaa3c86a59899c3920219386a5b6d1b587ca9/tests/LinqKit.Tests.Net452/ExpandableAttributeTests.cs#L60)