# Call another function inside custom Linq Expression

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have this code which is successfully translated to SQL:

```
public class MachineUtils 
{
    public static Expression<Func<Machine, bool>> IsDaily()
    {
        return model => (model.Distribution == EmailType.Daily) ||
                         model.IncludeMail;
    }
}

var query = _dbContext.Machines.AsNoTracking().Where(MachineUtils.IsDaily());
```

But I need to extract check logic to separate function for avoiding code duplication in the app.

So I need something like that, because I want to call `CheckIsDaily` function in other places in the app:

```
public class MachineUtils 
{
    public static bool CheckIsDaily(IMachine model)
    {
        return (model.Distribution == EmailType.Daily) ||
                model.IncludeMail;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<Machine, bool>> IsDaily()
    {
        return model => CheckIsDaily(model);
    }
}
```

In this case however, I get an error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Where(m => MachineUtils.CheckIsDaily(m))' could not be translated

How to achieve that?

Comment: Check [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70929584/10646316), it is similar.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're encountering that error is because Entity Framework is not able to translate the CheckIsDaily method call into SQL since it's a custom method and not a built-in SQL function. To achieve your goal of avoiding code duplication while still being able to use the logic in LINQ queries, you can use a combination of Expression Trees and custom reusable predicates.

```
public static class MachineUtils 
{
    public static Expression<Func<IMachine, bool>> CheckIsDailyPredicate = model =>
        (model.Distribution == EmailType.Daily) ||
        model.IncludeMail;

    public static Expression<Func<IMachine, bool>> IsDaily()
    {
        return CheckIsDailyPredicate;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the CheckIsDailyPredicate in your LINQ queries:

```
var query = _dbContext.Machines.AsNoTracking().Where(MachineUtils.CheckIsDailyPredicate);
```

This way, you've defined the logic as a reusable expression tree, and Entity Framework can translate it to SQL because it's working with expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MachineUtils
{
    public static bool CheckIsDaily(IMachine model)
    {
        return (model.Distribution == EmailType.Daily) || model.IncludeMail;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<Machine, bool>> IsDaily()
    {
        var method = typeof(MachineUtils).GetMethod(nameof(CheckIsDaily), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var model = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Machine), "model");
        
        var call = Expression.Call(method, model);

        // Create a lambda expression for model => CheckIsDaily(model)
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Machine, bool>>(call, model);
        return lambda;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error 'The LINQ expression '...' could not be translated'

Comment: Try Installing the LINQKit extension.